# ADOMD client in Mono

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mono, ssas

I have installed Ubuntu(v 14.04) and MonoDevelop(v 4.0.12). I wish to connect to SSAS (Analysis Services) from a C# application run on Linux (Ubuntu). I am trying to import Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll in my C# code. Even after adding reference to this dll I am unable to compile the code because of the dll.

I wish to know does MonoDevelop support ADOMD.NET ?
If ADOMD.NET is not supported in Mono, is there any way to connect to Analysis server using C#, Mono and Linux ?

Comment: What do you need to run? Just a few MDX queries? It might be possible to develop a subset of the functionality needed by accessing the http interface. You would need to send the requests as XML and parse the XML sent as response.

Comment: @frank : Thanks for replying but I dint get how can we do this. Yes I need just need to run some MDX queries but before that I will have to connect to the Analysis Server Cube. May you please help me in connecting a Linux PC with SSAS using C# ?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually connect to Analysis Services on the XMLA/SOAP level as follows:

First setup an http proxy to Analysis Services as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx). You can then contact the IIS application via http POST requests, which will forward your request to the Analysis Services server, and return the result as XML.

Using any development environment, send an http POST request to the http URL configured in the above step (e. g. https://YourServer.example.com/olap/msmdpump.dll) containing the following XML in the body:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Execute xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
      <Command>
        <Statement>
          select [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].Members
                 on columns,
                 [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].Members
                 on rows
            from [Adventure Works]
        </Statement>
      </Command>
      <Properties>
        <PropertyList>
          <Catalog>Adventure Works DW 2008</Catalog>
          <Format>Tabular</Format>
        </PropertyList>
      </Properties>
    </Execute>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

You will then get back the result as XML in one of two formats, either tabular (more similar to a relational result set) or multidimensional, where you get a list of axes, and then a list of cells. To set the format, either keep the query as in my code above, or change the `<Format>Tabular</Format>` to `<Format>Multidimensional</Format>` to get the result in multidimensional format. The interpretation of this result is then of course up to your application. But - depending on the variability of the possible MDX statements - you only need to code what you need in your application.

The content of the `Statement` XML element is your MDX select statement. Please be aware that - as this is XML - you will have to escape some special characters like `<`, `>` and `&` in this statement and use `&lt;`, `&gt;`, and `&amp;` instead.

And it really has to be an http post request, a get request will cause errors.